# Writing a Mini-Filter Device Driver in Windows

Tags: windows, filter-driver

I want to implement a *Mini-Filter Driver* in Windows that does the following:

1. Whenever a file is open, it needs to print the name of it.
2. If the name of a file is "testme.txt" then try to find a string "hello" in it. If it is found, then the operation needs to fail, otherwise it should print "testme.txt is clean”.

Can anyone help me to apply these requirements to write a program that fulfills these requirements?

Comment: What does "print" even mean in a mini-filter driver?  I guess you can display strings to the kernel debugger.

Comment: Where are you stuck?What have you implemented so far?

Comment: hello , thanks for you replay , ..
i am finished a big part of the program requirements , but it's i faced som some problem in last requirement !! 
this is my code !   
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysg0dmcmqqtflng/FsFilter1.c?dl=0

Comment: @Efi  ,, see what i write in the link if you can .